# import multisig wallet into bitcoin core, Vpub keys are not valid. how to?

Tags: bitcoin-core, multi-signature, public-key, xpub

I'm trying to import an HD multisig wallet created with Electrum into Bitcoin core v0.21.0.0.

I managed to do so with the fantastic [cryptoadvance.specter](https://specter.solutions/) server, but I also would like to import it using the standard bitcoin-cli commands.

This is what I managed to do so far, and it only works if I [convert](https://jlopp.github.io/xpub-converter/) the pub keys Vpub `Multi-signature P2WSH` to tpub `P2PKH`, so for example:

`Vpub5fRxfoprsHS9Vnhq1grZcJrWSRmSeBZbLCbnTJcvSDXr3xoBurx8MUt8UmHCsTVPXqk1rNpgt3X3KAvcJzCZvwn9yQymrWhwMJpEYysLqQV`

becomes

`tpubD8a2g9FwJxvC3c7YBvwvQL35Ph7jJTN4PnarTPCJAND6HGXSizk4ew1JxWKgqLXZuZSZ6KXZTFfgem2ar1itGNUywE1XJTY9azG4WBr25hn`

then I can run this program and it seems to be working fine, unless it's not because the resulting addresses are very different. (the wallet created with Specter matches perfectly the one in Electrum, it finds the correct transactions as well)

```
#!/bin/sh

wallet=$1
pub1=$2
pub2=$3

echo "Making wallet '${wallet}' from ${pub1} ${pub2}"

rawdescriptor="wsh(sortedmulti(2,${pub1}/*,${pub2}/*))"
descriptor=$(bitcoin-cli getdescriptorinfo $rawdescriptor | jq -r '.descriptor')
bitcoin-cli deriveaddresses  ${descriptor} "[0,0]"

bitcoin-cli createwallet $wallet true
bitcoin-cli -rpcwallet=$1  importmulti '[{"desc": "'$descriptor'", "internal": false, "range": [0, 1000], "timestamp": 1609459200, "keypool": true, "watchonly": true, "label": "lol"}]' '{ "rescan": true}'
# bitcoin-cli -rpcwallet=$1 rescanblockchain
```

I can't use the Vpub keys because bitcoin-cli (v0.21.0.0) throws this message:

```
key 'vpub5UXsYa6RJKsn5DYT52PanEWhidjBRpt11vx7Y3MP4ShSRnEH9TZrGN2Cg4KjK2GVJNg2ynpZzq8YC1Jr1m3cnTfV8wsNT7EwTaYMy4PCDAg' is not valid.
```

At this stage i’m only interested into a watch only wallet, so i don’t need to use private keys.

Also, I'm in testnet and I have `testnet=1` on my bitcoin.conf

I've tried reading as much as I could but I think i hit a wall now and I don't know how to continue.
Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: You're trying this with testnet funds, right?

Comment: yes, i’ll edit my question

Comment: Did you ever get this to work? I'm having the exact same issue on 0.21. barely any docs on the matter.

Comment: In fact I did! i'll answer my question, hold on

Comment: Actually I just kind of succeeded too. I wonder if we have the same solution :)
So I was using the root key signatures from seedpicker, where I got the Vpubs, but now I tried the master fingerprints from Specter PDF with SLIP132 and got the same addresses. What I still don't know is
a. where I can independently get the correct signature without relying on Specter and 
b. why the addresses imported are completely out of order and 
c. why bitcoin-qt does not show past transactions (I'm on a pruned node, so that could be the reason...)

Comment: see my answer for that, it should give you enough info

Comment: I used this guide. I understand you completely ignored the fingerprint and derivation path?

Comment: /0/* is the derivation path for receive addresses where /1/* is for change addresses, you use the script i pasted like this script.sh wallet_name vpub1... vpub2... vpub3... 0 "0,100"

Comment: I didn't mean the receive and change derivation paths. I means the key derivation path. When I created the descriptor I used the following format:
wsh(sortedmulti(2,[XXXXXXXX/48h/1h/0h/2h]tpubDFfbToY......e8dAX/0/*, ...

Comment: right, I ignored that. turned out it worked fine

Comment: Interesting. I also have a question for 'a' above. When converting the Vpub to tpub lopp's tool also gave me a new fingerprint, which I promptly (at least at first) ignored. Still wondering about the order of the addresses. Thanks for the info!

Comment: if it worked for you accept the answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is a script that works for me, it imports a 2of3 HD multisig wallet.

I have very basic knowledge of bash so you may want to double check it before running it, anyway, what finally worked for me was to understand that I had to `wsh(sortedmulti(2,${pub1}/0/*,${pub2}/0/*,${pub3}/0/*))`to derive the receive descriptor and `wsh(sortedmulti(2,${pub1}/1/*,${pub2}/0/*,${pub3}/0/*))`for receiver.

I also found this good converter here:
https://jlopp.github.io/xpub-converter/

```
#!/bin/sh

wallet=$1
pub1=$2
pub2=$3
pub3=$4
startfrom=$5
range=$6

wallet="${wallet:=test}"
pub1="${pub1:=Vpub1...}"
pub2="${pub2:=Vpub2...}"
pub3="${pub3:=Vpub3...}"
rescanblockchain="${startfrom:=1934907}"
range="${range:=[0,100]}"

p1=$(echo $pub1 | cut -c1-10)
p2=$(echo $pub2 | cut -c1-10)
p3=$(echo $pub3 | cut -c1-10)

printf "\n\nWorking on '${wallet}' from ${p1}... ${p2}... ${p3} starting from ${rescanblockchain}\n\n"

# create wallet if needed
if [[ $(bitcoin-cli listwallets | jq '. | index("'$wallet'")' ) == "null" ]]; then
    echo "Making wallet '${wallet}' from ${pub1} ${pub2} ${pub3}"
    bitcoin-cli createwallet $wallet  true
fi

# convert keys format from vpub to tpub https://jlopp.github.io/xpub-converter/
pub1=$(node converter.js ${pub1})
pub2=$(node converter.js ${pub2})
pub3=$(node converter.js ${pub3})

# get descriptor for receive addresses
raw_receive_descriptor="wsh(sortedmulti(2,${pub1}/0/*,${pub2}/0/*,${pub3}/0/*))"
receive_descriptor=$(bitcoin-cli getdescriptorinfo $raw_receive_descriptor | jq -r '.descriptor')

# get descriptor for change addresses
raw_change_descriptor="wsh(sortedmulti(2,${pub1}/1/*,${pub2}/0/*,${pub3}/0/*))"
change_descriptor=$(bitcoin-cli getdescriptorinfo $raw_change_descriptor | jq -r '.descriptor')

# import receive addresses
bitcoin-cli -rpcwallet=$wallet importmulti  '[{"desc": "'$receive_descriptor'", "internal": false, "range": '${range}', "timestamp": "now", "keypool": true, "watchonly": true}]'  '{"rescan": false}' | jq .

# import change addresses
bitcoin-cli -rpcwallet=$wallet importmulti  '[{"desc": "'$change_descriptor'", "internal": true, "range": '${range}', "timestamp": "now", "keypool": true, "watchonly": true}]'  '{"rescan": false}' | jq .

# rescan blockchain
bitcoin-cli -rpcwallet=$wallet rescanblockchain "${rescanblockchain}" | jq .

# just print out few receive addresses
bitcoin-cli deriveaddresses  ${receive_descriptor} "${range}" | jq .

# print out balance
bitcoin-cli -rpcwallet=$wallet getbalance
```

Answer (score 0):

So just to make this post more clear, this can be run directly on bitcoin-cli or in the bitcoin-qt console. Mostly I followed [this guide](https://www.reddit.com/r/Bitcoin/comments/gvwk4p/howto_setup_your_multisignature_cold_wallet_in/).
instead of Vpubs, I used Jameson Lopp's [converter](https://jlopp.github.io/xpub-converter/) to convert the Vpubs into tpubs, and while there I get the matching fingerprints, so I have everything I need.
Mind you, this is just to verify receive addresses independently from any other wallet (Electrum, Specter).

Sorry I can't upvote or do anything else, I am a first time user with 0 reputation :(